# Using cursor in my mongodb database, need guidance on fixing my queries

Tags: mongodb, count, attributes, cursor

So right now I want to use cursor to find all restaurants which are good for groups, have a price range less than or equal to three and have more than 50 reviews that have reviews with at least 5 "useful" votes;

```
db.business.find({$and:[{"attributes": /.*GoodForGroups: True.*/i},{review_count:{$gte:50}},{"attributes.RestaurantsPriceRange2":{$lte:3}}]})
```

But so far this query turn up nothing, so is there anything wrong with it?

Also this is what I can think of for my cursor so far, feel free to change it if you see anything wrong with it.

var myCursor=db.business.find({$and:[{"attributes": /.*GoodForGroups: True.*/i},{review_count:{$gte:50}},{"attributes.RestaurantsPriceRange2":{$lte:3}}]},{business_id:true, _id: false})

```
while(myCursor.hasNext()){
 db.reviews.find({$and:[{business_id:myCursor.next().business_id},{"useful":{$gte: 5}}]});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need the $and in your query, mongodb by default perform a $and.
Secondly, you are trying to query keys of your document, it is not possible.
Thirdly, your GoodForGroups should have a boolean value. You don't need a regex here.

Please run:

```
db.business.find({"attributes.GoodForGroups": true},{review_count:{$gte:50}},{"attributes.RestaurantsPriceRange2":{$lte:3}})
```

Comment: hey sir I fixed it now, I posted a new question can you tak e a look?

Comment: also sir, i"ve tried this, but get 0, db.business.count({$and:[{"attributes": /.*GoodForGroups: True.*/i},{review_count:{$gte:50}},{"attributes.RestaurantsPriceRange2":{$lte:3}}]} )
0